# Secure django session cookies are overriden when a non-secure page is used

Tags: django, session, cookies, ssl

Setting `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True` in Django tells the browser to only send the session cookie over SSL.  However, if an authenticated user navigates from a secure page to a non-secure page the session middleware will not know about the secure session (since the cookie won't be sent) and will set a new session cookie.  The effect is that the user is then logged out, and needs to log in again.

For example, a user might edit something in the secure admin, click "view on site", is taken to a non-ssl page, then clicks back, only to find that their session has been overwritten, and is no longer authenticated.

I'm just wondering what the preferred approach would be to solve this issue.

As I can see, there are the following solutions:

1. Use different (sub)domains for the secure / non-secure parts of the site.  Force everything on the ssl domain to be ssl.  (I know this would probably be the preferred option, but is currently not an option)
2. Use different django projects (and different session cookie names) for the secure / non-secure parts of the site.  Use nginx to proxy to appropriate django project.
3. Create a custom middleware based on `django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware` that manually handles sessions differently depending on secure / non-secure.  Perhaps even check whether the url is an admin url, and use a different cookie name and cookie path.
4. Set `SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = False` and hope that the user doesn't navigate to pages that use cookies.

Comment: How "not an option" is #1? It's by far the best idea, security-wise.

Comment: It's an option down the track, but need a quick fix now :-) I know option 1 is the by far the best option, but basically, I just want to make sure options 2-4 aren't opening up any other more big security issues that I haven't foreseen.

Comment: Unfortunately, they are. The chances of a mistake (and the consequences of a mistake) for 2-4 make me shudder. How confident are you that you'll _never_ mix up where a request is supposed to go? The safest option by far is to partition your site into secure and insecure sections and mandate SSL for the secure section.

Comment: Yeah, I'm definitely not that confident I'll never make a mistake!  I'm just not currently in a position to make those changes for this site -- I'd have to get approval, budget, time, etc :-(

Setting `SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = False` fixed the logging out issue.  I'll be suggesting option 1 for the future though, since we already do that for new projects.